# When Checkbox checked make other same value checkboxes disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make other same value checkbox disabled when one checked.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value = '1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value = '2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value = '1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value = '2'>
```

Comment: Have you tried? If so what have you tried? This is not a code writing service but happy to help if you get stuck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your question is far too broad and appears to lack any research or attempt at solving the problem. Read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com), go through some tutorials, and try to do the work. If you run into a **specific** problem doing so, post a question showing what you've tried and saying where you're stuck and we can help you with it.

Comment: just a question why would you have 2 checkbox with same value ? or 2 checkbox which is the same?

Comment: i have a week Calendar if one checked other disabled. calendar link - http://week-number.net/calendar-with-week-numbers-2016.html in this link  checkbox does not exist but i created every week checkbox/

Comment: add more information to OP add what you have tried what you expect and what is happening to your current code. unless you want to be down voted to oblivion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that should work if you want to disable only the other checkbox with the same value and not the checkbox who is checked :

```
$("input[name='check[]']").on('click', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var parent = $(this);
  $("input[value='"+val+"']").each(function() {
    $(this).not(parent).attr('disabled', parent.is(':checked'));
  });
})
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lenauevf/1/)

Answer (score 7):

Use a [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler and disable other elements based on the checked property. Where you can get other elements with same value using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```js
// cache the elements
var $chk = $("[name='check[]']");
// bind change event handler
$chk.change(function() {
  $chk
    // remove current element
    .not(this)
    // filter out element with same value
    .filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]')
    // update disabled property based on the checked property
    .prop('disabled', this.checked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='2'>
```

Comment: thanks it perfectly worked for me..

Comment: Hi, How can I do this the opposite way?. disabling checkboxes if value of the checked checkbox is not the same with it? thanks

Comment: @Dre : use `.filter(':not([value="' + this.value + '"])')` or `.not('[value="' + this.value + '"]')` instead of `.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]')`

Answer (score 0):

your html :

```
    <input type='checkbox' class="chk" id="chk_id" name='check[]' value = '1'>
    <input type='checkbox' class="chk" id="chk_id" name='check[]' value = '2'>
    <input type='checkbox' class="chk" id="chk_id" name='check[]' value = '1'>
    <input type='checkbox' class="chk" id="chk_id" name='check[]' value = '2'>
```

Your script :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#chk_id").click(function(){
        var current_value = $(this).val();
              $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == current_value){
                  $(this).attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });

       }); 
  });
```