# jQuery - Check checkbox and disable other if has different value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to disable other `checkbox` if the checked `checkbox` has different value with the others. I've seen one question but the answer is the opposite of it. any answers is well appreciated.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Active'> //first checkbox
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Inactive'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Inactive'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Active'>
```

let say `first checkbox` is checked with the value of `Active`. other checkboxes with a value of `Inactive` should be disabled `on change`.

Here is the example I've found from one of the devs here

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Lenauevf/1/

[When Checkbox checked make other same value checkboxes disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056093/when-checkbox-checked-make-other-same-value-checkboxes-disabled#)

Comment: add all related code to OP not in an external link

Comment: So you want to disabled checkboxes with `Inactive` value only when first checkbox is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input[name='check[]']").on('click', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var parent = $(this);
        $("input[value !='"+val+"']").each(function() {
            $(this).not(parent).attr('disabled', parent.is(':checked'));
        });
    })
```

Comment: nice work, how can i also do this if I use `data attribute`? instead of `value` thanks!

Comment: You can use $.data(attr) to get the value of the attribute of each input tag, the do the same way as you do width the attribute 'name'

Answer (score 1):

1. Get current value of the change checkbox on change event.
2. Uncheck all the checkbox.
3. Use the current value to check all checkbox with same value

```js
$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val)
  $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
  $(":checkbox[value=" + val + "]").prop("checked", true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Active'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Inactive'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Inactive'>
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='Active'>
```

Comment: nice work, how can i also do this if I use `data attribute`? instead of `value` thanks!

Comment: just change the value with the attribute `$(":checkbox[data-value=" + val + "]")` for `<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' data-value='Active'>` @dre